# Using passed block in another block

Tags: ruby, select, block

Is it possible to call something like this:

```
def foo(param1)
   hash.select { |k,v| yield }.each do |x|
      res += do_something_with(v,param1)
   end
   res 
end
```

from an ERB template like:

```
<%= foo('A',{ v.field!='X' }) %>
```

to achieve customized select on my hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby you can get the passed block as the last parameter if you add a leading `&` in front of the parameter name, for instance `&block`, the `block` variable will then be the `Proc` passed to the method.

`block` will be nil if no block was passed.

To forward the block, call a method and add as the last parameter `&block`

So now, let's deal with your issue :

Get the block at the last argument of the method and pass it to the `select` method:

```
def foo(param1, &block)
   hash.select(&block).each do |x|
      res += do_something_with(v,param1)
   end
   res 
end
```

You could also do something like `.select { |v| yield(v) }` but this is less elegant :)

Your view has a small problem, here is the corrected version :

```
<%= foo('A') { |v| v.field!='X' } %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was near this answer during my efforts, but apparently I lack some ruby syntax related topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a block as a parameter by prefixing it with and `&`:

```
def foo(&param1)
```

And then you can you the `block_given?` test:

```
if block_given?
  #do something with param1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method foo does something that is mostly presentation related, and that you need it to be accessible from a view, the best place to have it is probably a Helper. All methods declared in Helpers can be used from erb templates.

You can pass a block from a method to another, using the & synthax :

```
def foo(values,&action)
  #pass &action to whatever method need it.
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not going rails here. Rails is pretty heavy for my endpoint, which is ASUS RT-N16 (running Ruby 1.9.1, server-WEBRick)